# Key difference between PID and LQI integral terms

Tags: control-theory

I am working on control theory implementation on quadcopters. So far I have empirically implemented a [PID](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pid.html?searchHighlight=pid&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) and an [LQI](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqi.html) (Linear Quadratic Integral) controllers and tested them. I got a MUCH robust performance from LQI in terms of noise and disturbance rejection, and model uncertainties (click [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7984252) for detailed analysis).

However, I understand that the PID control output u is:

u(s) = [Kp + Ki/s + Kd*s]*e(s)

and the LQI output is:

u(s) = -Kx * x(s) - Ki * xi(s)

My question is mainly about the integral term in each controller. Both of the controllers integrate the error e and have a zero at the origin. How is the LQI controller is better (more robust) that the PID one?

Answer (score 2):

This is not always true though in general it is practically true since PID control tuning is a local optimization problem compared to the state feedback+integrator design.

What the difference is that in the LQI control you are using the state information to control the system and driving the steady state error quicker with an extra integrator.

In PID case however you are using the output of the system which (assuming observability and controllability) cannot immediately have all the information. Imagine there are two states a fast one and a rather slow one and you are only observing a strange combination of them encoded in your `C` matrix. PID works on that observed quantity whereas LQI works with both states simultaneously.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. What if I have a MIMO system with the outputs equal some states, say [y1; y2; y3] = [x1; x3; x5],                                                     then what will be the difference between PID and LQI in this case?

Comment: @M.A. LQ always uses **full** state feedback. That means you are using an estimator such as LQG. Control comparison is not done via methods but measurable performance quantities.